# showing &quot; in td instead of <

Tags: php, text, html-table, formatted

I am storing formatted string in database using PHP.
And displaying that string in td of HTML table.
My sample text is like-

```
<font color="#0033CC"><b>water </b>releasing<i> H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup></i> ions; </font>
```

When displaying in td, it just displaying this raw data instead of formatted text. I have viewed the source in browser and found below data.

```
<td>&lt;font color=&quot;#0033CC&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;water &lt;/b&gt;releasing&lt;i&gt; H&lt;sub&gt;3&lt;/sub&gt;O&lt;sup&gt;+&lt;/sup&gt;&lt;/i&gt; ions; &lt;/font&gt;</td>`
```

That means " is replaced with `&quot;` > is replaced with `&gt;` and so on.

Is there any built in approach in PHP to avoid this scenario and displaying formatted text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the code you use to output this

Comment: You've encoded the HTML string somewhere, you'll need to decode it on output. Also, see ^.

Comment: Check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Check how the database has that string stored - I've got a suspicion that you're using a wysiwyg editor to put that data into the database and that's (unnecessarily) using `htmlentities()` as a sanitisation step before inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.html-entity-decode.php);

```
<?php
$orig = 'J\'ai "sorti" le <strong>chien</strong> tout à l\'heure';
$a = htmlentities($orig);
$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // J'ai &quot;sorti&quot; le &lt;strong&gt;chien&lt;/strong&gt; tout &amp;agrave; l'heure
echo $b; // J'ai "sorti" le <strong>chien</strong> tout à l'heure

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i made the mistake during storing the data.
I was using below methods to process data first.
   //$data = stripslashes($data);
   //$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
after commenting these two methods resolved my problem

Comment: No you didn't...is ok to add to the database stings like that. Please leave the htmlspecialchars() and after you get the string from the database use htmlspecialchars_decode() and everything will be ok. @mirzapinku

Comment: @M.I. there's no real reason to use `htmlentities()` on strings going into the database (if you *want* to store html data anyway); personally I think it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @CD001 if he's getting some input as html from a user, shouldn't he at least escape it before adding it to the DB ?

Comment: @M.I. not really - there's no danger in inserting HTML into a database table (via a prepared statement with bound parameters), the danger comes when putting it back on the screen. Most likely the data will be going into the database via a managed CMS with a WYSIWYG editor, in which case you *want* HTML in and out so there's no point encoding it. If it's a publicly available form, you probably don't want to allow HTML **at all** so you'd be better off with `strip_tags()` or *HTMLPurifier* if you absolutely must allow *some* HTML.

Comment: @CD001 Nice, thanks for the explanation. I never had to store html in the database, hope it won't be necessary in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not encode HTML special chars before saving data.
You'd better do it **just before `print`/`echo`**.

```
<?php

function h($str)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

$data = get_something_data_from_database();    

/* More logic... */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<div><?=h($data)?></div>
```

Yes, `<?=h(...)?>` is an idiom. ( `<?=...?>` is the short syntax of `echo`)

Or do you need to allow that users input raw HTML? Without no filtering or validation, it brings us the major **vulnerability**: *[Cross Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)*. You need to use *[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)* for this purpose.